# Running a Java code in cmd is not working while everything is fine in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, cmd

I wrote the code below in Eclipse and trying to do the same in cmd. However I in cmd the error message :

> Error: Could not find or load main class GetMousePosition.

In cmd, I am in the folder where they class is : c:\Java\Examples\src\Robots\

When I compile the class (doing : javac GetMousePosition), everything works fine.

Originally, I set up my java's bin folder path in the environment variables.

Thanks in advance for your help

```
package Robots;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GetMousePosition {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation());
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you type when you try to run your class ? What happened (what was the output ?) Which directory are you in when you try to run your class, and in which directory is the GetMousePosition.class file ?

Comment: I type java GetMousePosition and I am in c:\Java\Examples\src\Robots\ (the folder of GetMousePosition.java).

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the *full* class name on the command line, in this case `Robots.GetMousePosition`.  java may also assume that your class is in the right directory structure, so you should probably move up one directory.

Answer (score 2):

You need to back up one directory (to `c:\Java\Examples\src\`) and then run

`java Robots.GetMousePosition`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to specify the main class. Eclipse can not find the class that has a main method.

For this you need to

Right click the file in the view -> run as -> Run configuration and there you need to select the class that has main method.

For detailed guide follow this: [Set Eclipse launch configuration](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-java-local-configuration.htm)